# Shopify Stylesheet - CodeMirror? 99% unused

Tags: css, shopify, code-coverage

I've got this stylesheet loading on the index, but I can't seem to find the source anywhere. After researching CodeMirror, I'm guessing it has to do with the page customizer?

Is there any way to disable this stylesheet?

[image]

Comment: Are you logged in to Shopify? Or is that also being served to anonymous users?

Answer (score 4):

This stylesheet is not included in the code of theme.liquid
It's loaded via the {{content_for_header}} in the head section.

It is not coming from an app, as one would suggest,
Its coming from Shopify and is only loaded, when previewing a theme.

It is a little misleading when you are trying to get the page-load down and you are using the developer tools from chrome.

Inspect the theme again after it's live or block the requested URL in dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

If the stylesheet is included in the layout/theme.liquid file, then you can comment out or remove it there.

If it is not included in that file, there is a good chance that it is coming from a Shopify app store app. If that is the case, you would have to check that app for settings, or not use that app.